# Parse google directions data for transit and use it to display map in activity in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to parse data from google APIs for transit b/w two places and display that data in my activity using google maps.Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/iamamused/Google-Maps-Directions-API-Java-Parser